# jframe component layout

Tags: java, swing, layout

How can I specify the location on JFrame that a component (JLabel specifically) is placed? I created a JFrame object and added a JLabel and a JList to the frame but both objects are being placed on top of each other.  I have tried using

`label.setBounds(10,10,10,10);

list.setBounds(20,20,100,100);`

and

`label.setLocation(10,10);

list.setLocation(10, 50);`

Neither of these are working.  Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: can you provide the code where you create the `JFrame`, `JLabel` and `JList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, layout managers are used which determine the way the components will be placed. You can find more information about layout managers here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

If you definitely want to use coordinates to put your components, you could try:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(null);
```

Otherwise, a very good GUI editor for Java is NetBeans which is using the GroupLayout by default.

Comment: Setting the layout manager to null is the preferred way to use absolute positioning when laying out components. however IMO, the GUI Editor for NetBeans is a real pain and I find it easier to not use it.

Comment: The NetBeans UI editor is excellent and right now one of the best there is available for free. Learning how the different LayoutManagers work can be difficult, but it will be well worth it in the end.

Answer (score 1):

[Layout Managers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) will do that for you.

With the default Layout `BorderLayout`, try

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
getContentPane().add(yourLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
getContentPane().add(yourList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```